# Edit an element in the list view of a calendar web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list-view, calendar

I added a calendar web part to my site, and it's default view is a list view.
The problem is that I can't edit all the columns (example: periodicity) in the list view.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your response.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the column type of column `Periodicity`? Can you add screenshot of column settings and your calendar web part view?

Comment: Periodicité is like frequency (Every week)

Comment: So you are not able to edit it from Edit form or Quick Edit(Datasheet view) of list view?

Comment: no, I cant edit it from there. On the second screenshot the field is grayed and not clickable. I can add the an item from the list view with periodicité but I can't edit the item in this list view.

Comment: Is it Recurrance column? Is there any custom code added on form?

Comment: Yes, it's a recurrence column. But why isn't the edit form appearing when I double click on the element in the list view ?